# NPM Cache Step not working in Azure DevOps

Tags: android, node.js, azure, caching, npm

I followed the following doc from Microsoft to configure the npm cache step for android app i am trying to build in azure and instead of package.json-Lock i am using package.json.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm

I am able to upload the cache dependency file in the post-cache step and upload that file in the beginning correctly when running the pipeline for 2nd time but even after the npm cache data is downloaded in the workspace the npm install step is still calling the remote libraries and downloading the remote dependencies.

I have also tried to run **npm install --prefer-offline** for the npm install step but did work. Please let me know if i am missing anything more.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `Cache` task to cache your application's node_modules folder. Use the cache hit variable (`cacheHitVar`) to store the result of the cache restoration. It will be set to `true` when the cache is restored (cache hit), otherwise set to `false`.

Then use a condition for the task that installs your dependencies (e.g. `npm ci`). Only install them on a cache miss.

```
steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: Cache node_modules
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/package-lock.json'
      path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/node_modules
      cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Install the dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: custom
      verbose: false
      customCommand: 'ci'
    condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
```

You'll see the following output in the pipeline execution when the cache was restored successfully.

[image: Azure Pipeline Execution]

Comment: Does this require adding package-lock.json to git (not ignored)?

Comment: @JBS Yes, since the cache key is partially based on the lock file and the npm ci command is used which requires a lock file. Regardless of this issue, I would recommend adding the lock file to your Git repository. This way when other developers clone the repository locally, they will install the same versions of the dependencies.  To avoid issues such as "works on my machine". You don't want direct or transient dependencies updated without your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @Christophe. I tried this approach and in my case the Cache method actually took longer - downloading the stored cache took long, probably because of connection and performance limitations of the build server (not using a cloud based agent). In my case it was quickest to use `npm install --prefer-offline --no-audit`

Comment: I had similar experiences on Azure DevOps. The time gained by caching it was not worth it in the end. Sometimes it was slower due to network latency. It would help if you have a private package registry with a cap on the data usage.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers - Is it better to use the conditional caching that You posted or ```customCommand: 'ci --cache $(npm_config_cache)'``` ? Any pros & cons in favor of chosen solution?

Comment: Using this approach, I keep getting the error "There is a cache miss." both on the Cache node_modules step (which doesn't fail the build) as well as on the Post-job: Cache node_modules step step (which does fail the build.) Any ideas?

Comment: @Justin The cache key is determined by the key property of the Cache@2 task. Did your agent, sources directory or package-lock.json change?

Comment: The error message was misleading, we didn't have "tar" installed on the build server. We ended up upgrading from windows server 2016 to 2020, which has it built-in, then the caching started working. (Although it ended up being even slower than the actual npm downloading!)

Comment: Yes, that was my experience as well. It takes about the same time or even longer. If speed is the only reason there is little to be gained.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers The issue with doing it like this is that if you are making a component library and the build pipeline updates the package version, the cache ID will be different each time because the package-lock hash will be different each time. Do you have any suggestions to make sure that the cache isn't used when actual packages change but is used when just the version changes?

Answer (score 7):

Please check the following official recommendation from Microsoft regarding node modules caching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm

```yaml
variables:
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
    path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm

- script: npm ci
```

> Because npm ci deletes the node_modules folder to ensure that a consistent, repeatable set of modules is used, you should **avoid caching node_modules** when calling npm ci.

Comment: I get `tar: can't change directory to '/home/azureuser/azpwork/agent/azpwork/2/.npm': No such file or directory`. There is no .npm file or directory on the linux agent.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much of an answer, because i have the exact same problem however this is my setup.

```
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Cache npm
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/XX/package-lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
    path: $(npm_config_cache)

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: Npm restore dependencies
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: '$(clientapps)'
    customCommand: 'install --cache $(npm_config_cache)'
```

adding `--cache` sets npm's cache file to a specific location. i'm now running a build with --prefer-offline and see if that helps. i'll answer here if that helps.

Comment: did it help? The answers related to this seem to vary

Comment: I've got it setup with --prefer-offline in my pipeline, but it does not seem to matter - although it could also be that my package-lock.json changed between runs. My pipeline does not run often.... In anyway building still takes way longer that restore dependencies on my end - so i stopped looking into it. What you could try is to not run npm restore if restore from cache worked (the cache task can output a boolean, check the azure pipeline docs)  - but i don't know if that works.

Comment: I ran the pipeline some more as a test and it seems like it does not work anyways: `##[warning]The given cache key has changed in its resolved value between restore and save steps;` so the lockfile gets changed? anyways - i'm doing something wrong but i won't be investigating further at this time..

Comment: Ah - its because i'm using npm install which rewrites the file, i should use npm ci but that gave errors so i could not use that. Caching therefore seems undoable at this time for me.